# Как отнять период от даты в PHP?

Tags: php

Имеем дату из БД
`$row['doomsday']` в формате 06.06.1666

Такое с данной датой работает:

```
$doomsday = date ("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['doomsday'])-60*60*48);  //отнимает 2 суток.
```

А как реализовать такое же, но через выражения - "day","month" и т.п.?
К примеру, чтобы как-то так было:

```
$doomsday = date ("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['doomsday'])-strtotime("-2 day")); 
$collapse_day = date ("d.m.Y", strtotime($row['collapse_day'])-strtotime("-1 month"));
```

Есть какое-нибудь решение такой задачи?

Comment: А сразу из БД нужные значения с интервалом нельзя взять?

Comment: [date_sub](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php) подойдет? или [date_modify](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е. как-то SQL запросом?
Тут надо учитывать, что в БД дата хранится, в текстовом формате.
И в голове быстрее всплыло решение по средствам PHP, нежели по средствам MySQL,

Comment: @I_CaR ну да. вы же в переменную `$row['doomsday']` и `$row['collapse_day']` данные достаете из БД. Так почему бы в этом самом запросе и не указать сразу как именно достать ту или иную дату

Comment: @I_CaR Ну как бы [да](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: @I_CaR что значит в текстовом формате? `varchar` или `text` чтоли?

Comment: Да какая разница в каком формате она там хранится (нехорошо конечно хранить даты в текстовом виде). На данную задачу это вообще никак не отразится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы принципиально ответы не пишете? Тут уже можно больше чем на одну строчку написать ;)

Answer (score 2):

Форум sources навёл на решение:

```
$reminder = date ("d.m.Y", strtotime("-1 month", strtotime($row['date_from_db'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для PHP >= 5.3 можно использовать удобный и выразительный объектный интерфейс:

```
// Исходную дату и интервал можно создать из строкового представления
$target_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', '06.06.1970');
$diff = \DateInterval::createFromDateString('2 days');

// Вычитаем из даты необходимый временной интервал.
$target_date->sub($diff);

echo($target_date->format('d.m.Y')); // Выведет "04.06.1970"
```